# MSMQ receives messages only from some clients

Tags: msmq

I have a non transactional Message Queue on a windows server 2008 (data center edition) with 31 clients. The connecting servers are not within the same workgroup or domain (don't know if that plays a role).

The problem is, that the queue only receives messages from some clients (9 actually) and the messages of the other clients are lost.

I can't find any error message in the windows event log. The MSMQ state on the clients says "connected" and the dead letter queues are empty... If I stop the MSMQ Service on the Server, the messages get correctly queued up on the client machines.

What other possible reasons for the loss of the messages should I look for? Can this behaviour be caused by any component inbetween?

**Scenario**

Each server (MSMQ client - there are 31) sends on every full minute a message to the MSMQ Server (message size about 40k Bytes). If I enable journaling I only see the messages from nine (instead of 31) servers on the MSMQ server, the other messages are lost. The messsages that are received are always from the same servers.

Answer (score 1):

Licences won't cause message loss. If licencing was a blocker, you would have clients without a CAL being unable to connect and messages remaining in their outgoing queue.
Messages disappear either because they have been read or their TTRQ/TTBR timers have expired.
There will be no events in the Windows event log.
You need to use journaling to track what happens to the messages.

Comment: Thanks, I tried journaling: I see only the messages from 10 Clients in the journal queue. That's the reason why I think that the messages get lost before they are read by the application.

Comment: OK, so you know they are not reaching the queue. Try positive and negative source journaling to track them in flight.

Comment: Thanks, John. It seems that the reason is that the servers are all clones: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/02/06/msmq-prefers-to-be-unique.aspx. But at the moment we'are still verifying this.

Comment: Wow - is it really 8 years since I wrote that blog post?

Comment: Now I see, it was your blog post! I really must thank you that you did write it. I almost did fall into despair.